# Differentiate v^2 in regards to time

Tags: calculus, derivatives, classical-mechanics

I'm working on some mechanics at the moment and can across this issue in a question.

Distance differentiated in regards to time becomes velocity: $dx/dt$. Differentiate velocity in regards to time and you get acceleration: $d^2x/dt^2$.

If I have $v^2$ and want to differentiate in regards to time, how would you go about doing so? Do I first write velocity as a differential, and how would I even do so $(dx/dt)^2$?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your title does not match the body.  The title asks for the time derivative of the acceleration, which you can do just fine.

Answer (score 2):

To find $\frac d{dt}\left(v^2\right)$ you use the chain rule $$\frac d{dt}\left(v^2\right)=2v\frac d{dt}v=2va$$
You can certainly write $v^2=\left(\frac {dx}{dt}\right)^2$ but that is not needed here.

Comment: How to you get the 2va? Would d/dt v^2 = d/dt dx/dt dx/dt = d^2x/dt^2 dx/dt = va?

Comment: Because $\frac d{dt}v=a$ is how the acceleration is defined.  When you wrote  d/dt v^2 = d/dt dx/dt dx/dt = d^2x/dt^2 dx/dt you forgot the parentheses.  It should be d/dt (dx/dt dx/dt)=  d^2x/dt^2 dx/dt+ dx/dt d^2x/dt^2  lading to the same result using the product rule.  Please review these basic differentiation rules.